# PHP redirect in onother url via user id

Tags: php, redirect

I want to do a simple text area that when a member put an id, you'll be redirect do the desired page with the id that you have putted before..
I.e. if my id is: 123456, i put it into and when i click go, i'll be redirected to `www.testsite.com/?p=details&amp;id=123456`
Can someone help me?

```
 <form action="" method="POST" onclick="submit" name="Formular">
          <font face="Arial">VID: </font>
          <input type="text" name="ID" size="6">
          <input type="submit" value="Weiter" name="B1">
        </form>
```

Bye

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Why don’t you just make the method GET, and set the action and field names accordingly …?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like that:

```
<?php
//Check ID is given - (prüfe ob ID übergeben wurde)
if(isset($_REQUEST['ID']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['ID']))
{
    header("LOCATION: http://www.testsite.com/?p=details&amp;id=".(int)$_REQUEST['ID']);
    exit;
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" onclick="submit" name="Formular">
    <font face="Arial">VID: </font>
    <input type="text" name="ID" size="6">
    <input type="submit" value="Weiter" name="B1">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```